# Local martingale property for stochastic integrals.

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, local-martingales

First we start with a Brownian Motion $B(t)$, $a\leq t\leq b$ and an admissible filtration for the BM $\{\mathcal F_t\}$.

Let $f(t,\omega)$ be a stochastic process satisfying:

1. $f(t)$ is adapted to the filtration $\{\mathcal F_t\}$
2. $\int_a^b |f(t)|^2 dt <\infty $ a.s.

Denote the space of all stochastic processes satisfying the latter $\mathcal L_{ad}(\Omega,L^2[a,b])$.

Then we have that

> Let $f\in \mathcal L_{ad}(\Omega,L^2[a,b])$ then 
>   $$X_t=\int_a^t f(s)dB(s), a\leq t\leq b$$
>   is a local martingale w.r.t to the filtration $\{\mathcal F_t\}$.

Nothing is further added about this theorem in my textbook , and I would like to understand the proof of the later, in particular I don't get how to find a localising sequence of stopping times.

There's one example that claims:

Let $f(t)=e^{B(t)^2}\in\mathcal L_{ad}(\Omega,L^2[a,b]) $,

Then $$X_t=\int_a^t e^{B(s)^2} dB(s)$$
 is a local martingale.

This is compatible with the theorem above but I am not sure how to properly prove this statement.

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The exact details of this may depend on the exact construction of the Ito integral you're using which varies from textbook to textbook. Which textbook are you following?

Comment: I am following "Introduction to stochastic integration" by Hui-Hsiung Kuo

Comment: In the copy I'm looking at the result you want is Theorem 5.5.2 on page 71. The proof of the result is contained in the discussion starting towards the end of the previous page and ending on the top of page 71. Have you read that discussion?

Comment: Actually I did, but I have difficulties to connect the discussion with the actual examples, in the one I've presented, the process $f(t)$ is square integrable, namely in $\Lambda^2$ if $t<1/4$, hence I could let $\tau_n=1/4$ and then the process $X_{min(t,\tau_n)}$ would be a martingale, but $\tau_n$ does not converge a.s. to $b$.

Comment: If $\tau_n$ does not converge to $b$ then it obviously won't do as a localising sequence. The discussion in the textbook tells you a good choice of localising sequence though so trying to come up with a new one seems unnecessary. The discussion is exactly a proof that the sequence of stopping times suggested there is a localising sequence.

Comment: I've had a second look at the discussion, and I might misunderstood something because now it's pretty clear what you are pointing out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not exactly an elementary proof. Assuming that you are well versed in the properties of the Ito integral for the class of integrands $\{f: E[\int_a^b f^2(s)\, ds] < \infty \}, $ and know how to prove the existence of a continuous martingale modification for the stochastic integral for this class, then the localizing sequence (do you know the exact definition of a localizing sequence here?) can be taken to be
 $$\tau_n =\inf\bigl\{s: \int_a^s f^2(\omega, t)\, dt > n\} \hskip 4pt \text{ and } \hskip 4pt \tau_n = b \hskip 4pt \text{ if } \hskip 4pt 
\int_a^b f^2(\omega, t)\, dt \le n $$

Check Steele's Stochastic Calculus and Financial Applications, instead.Or some other textbook on stochastic calculus that is still at a reasonable introductory level.